# using pdfkit in node.js to send an HTTP response

Tags: node.js, pdfkit

I am using pdfkit 0.6.1 in a node.js express 3 project.

I want to send the PDF as an HTTP Response instead of saving it on the server.

The example at http://pdfkit.org/docs/getting_started.html says to use:

```
# HTTP response
doc.pipe fs.createWriteStream(res) 

# add stuff to PDF here

# finalize the PDF and end the stream
doc.end()
```

However I am getting an error which says: "500 TypeError: path must be a string"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it will work fine if I use
    `doc.pipe res`
instead of
    `doc.pipe fs.createWriteStream(res)`